# How to dynamic render data after ajax with knockout.mapping.js?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using knockout.js & knockout.mapping.js.
I change data resource into ajax, the data couldn't refresh dynamically.

Because in actual project, I wanner customize html modules without change js code, and the data is not certain, so the data structure is complex and dynamic. Two main goals I want achieve:

1, multi-levels data, so I use knockout.mapping, but it's not working.
Here is a example: http://jsfiddle.net/8uKaL/

2, dynamic source, resources may be have `data2, data3, ...`, and I can change source ref from `data2` into `data3` easily, so I thought I should use something like `<div data-bind="foreach: resources_ajax(key)" data-key="data1">` in html.

Is there any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about this differently.   Knockout is about data-binding a model to the DOM, which will update the DOM on your behalf.  You look like are trying to "call the model" from the DOM

Updated your code to show example, the key part:

```
.done(function(data) {
      data.data1 = JSON.parse(data.data1); // this line just for fix fake ajax request
      self.resources_ajax(data.data1);
  });
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m389e/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my project, I wanner customize html modules without change js code, and the data is not certain. Two main goals I want achive: 1, dynamic source, resources may be have `data2`, `data3`, and I can change source ref from `data2` into `data3` easily, so I want use `data-key` in html. 2, multi-levels, so I use knockout.mapping.

Comment: @Fancyoung this is the kind of details you need to put in your question (preferably as soon as possible) so people have all the keys to help

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to make an empty data1 array first. http://jsfiddle.net/8uKaL/4/

```
// this will create resources_ajax.data1 as ko.observableArray()
self.resources_ajax = ko.mapping.fromJS({data1: []});
```

Otherwise, in your original code, before ajax, in your foreach binding, ko will see resources_ajax.data1 as `undefined`, and ko will never know you created a key `data1` in resources_ajax later on.

What ko can "observe" is the content change of resources_ajax.data1, not the creation of a key `data1` on resources_ajax object.

**UPDATE**

But the above solution doesn't solve your dynamic use case.

Here is a technique to let ko recreate the DOM after ajax.
http://jsfiddle.net/8uKaL/6/

wrap the DOM in a observable flag `loading`, before ajax, set `loading` to `true`, after ajax, set `loading` to `false`, this will force ko to re-parse the inner binding, and re-create the DOM.